# Polaris AV Capture USB analog TV device drivers needed

Tags: drivers, tv-tuner, video4linux, v4l

I already have a Mecer-branded USB analog TV tuner that I've been using under Windows. Now that I'm moving to Lubuntu I'd like to use it there as well. The product's minimalistic web page is [here](http://mecer.co.za/mecer-external-tv-tuner/). Running dmesg prints the following:

```
[ 8415.912276] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 8416.048214] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1b80, idProduct=d420
[ 8416.048226] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8416.048233] usb 2-1: Product: Polaris AV Capture
[ 8416.048240] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Conexant Corporation
[ 8416.048245] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 0000000000
```

Searching for Conexant Polaris AV Capture drivers lead me to try `sudo modprobe cx231xx` and to add that to /etc/modules. That shows up at boot time - `dmesg | grep cx231xx` gives

```
[    6.304299] usbcore: registered new interface driver cx231xx
```

The problem is that no `/dev/video0` device gets created. This made me suspect that I have the wrong driver so I went in search of the driver for USB device ID 1b80:d420. `lsusb` tells me this thing comes from Afatech. The best I could manage to find is that device IDs 1b80:e421 and 1b80:e424 are supported by the cx231xx driver ([according to this link](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/VIDEO_CX231XX.html)). [LinuxTV](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices) lists some USB DVB-T adapters with vendor ID 1b80 and they mention various Afatech chipsets (the device IDs listed are e410, e397, e402, e396, e39b, e395, e399, e400, c160, c810, 0x401, d393, e409, e411, d393). My device isn't listed (and its analog, not DVB-T). Please tell me where I can find a driver for this USB TV tuner, if it is even supported.

Comment: Any luck?  I have the same device.

Comment: Unfortunately not.